# Minimal polynomial of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $p,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $p$ prime and $q=p^n$. Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements (unique up to $\cong$), i.e. the $q$-th Galois field. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension), the extension $\mathbb{Z}_p\leq\mathbb{F}_q$ is simple, so we must have $$\mathbb{F}_q\cong\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f)$$
for some irreducible polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. What is the formula for this $f$?

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily unique.

Comment: Many comments say there is no "formula" to given an example of such an $f$ for any $n$ (with $p$ fixed). Is this expected? Said another way, is there a good reason for it? A plausible reason could take the form of "if we had such a formula, it would provide a formula for this related problem, which looks hopeless". Or something along those lines.

Comment: @rghthndsd: The behavior of irreducible polynomials is extraordinarily similar to the behavior of prime integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "formula" to produce an irreducible polynomial of arbitrary degree over an arbitrary finite field. There are, however, *algorithms*, which are basically just very complicated formulas. :)

Many computer algebra systems have a function for this. For example in Pari this function is called *ffinit*, and the documentation says it uses "a fast variant of Adleman and Lenstra's algorithm", which I suppose refers to http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1986a/art.pdf

Answer (score 2):

$f$ need not be unique. Take $\mathbf{Z}_5$ with $f=x^2-2,g=x^2-3$. Both give fields with $25$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, $f$ need not be unique. You can take $f$ to be any irreducible (over $\mathbb{F}_p$) polynomial of degree $n$, and for any root $\alpha$ of $f$, $\mathbb{F}_q \cong \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$

**Edit:** If you want explicit irreducible polynomials of a given degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, you can recursively use the fact that $x^{p^n} - x$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $d$ runs over divisors of $n$. E.g. over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $x^{p^2} - x = x^4 - x = x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$, so for $p = 2, n = 2$, there happens to be a unique irreducible polynomial defining $\mathbb{F}_4$ (but from this one can easily see that in general, there will be many such irreducibles).

Comment: Could you please provide an explicit formula for f, given $p$ and $n$.

Comment: Non-uniqueness means there are *many* possible $f$'s, for a given $p$ and $n$. Your use of the word formula seems to imply that you think there is only one such $f$

Comment: @Leon: There is no known formula even for an example of $f$ in general. When $p=2$ I use the entries in [this table](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/primitive-polynomial-table.txt), because those are *primitive*, i.e. minimal polynomials of a generator of the multiplicative group. (+1 to the three answers).